# svn problem - cannot work with my project anymore

Tags: svn

I got blue screen of death while working with my SVN repos.

Now i can browse through repos in browser 
but i cannot perform checkout, checkout, synch of my project...

I got "General server errors" for anything I try.

Is this some locking problem?

How can i recover?

Comment: Paste a command and the resultant error message in full, so we can attempt diagnosis.

Comment: I got 'malformed file on last revision' type of error on 'svnadmin dump' command

Comment: does the fresh checkout works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like that last change you did to the repository was caught up in the blue screen.  And based on your comment to your question, also sounds like the last change resulted in a corrupt revision in your repository. Basically rendering your repository in its current state useless.

Time to recover what we can.  Run the dump all the way up to the next to last revision.  The command should look something like:

`svnadmin dump -r9999 > repo_name_r0_9999.dump`

These commands assume there are 10000 revisions in your repo.  I think you have the idea now.  Now, load that dump into a new repo with a name like _new. The resulting command set should look like:

```
svnadmin create repo_new
svandmin load \path\to\repo_new < repo_name_r0_9999.dump
```

Copy the uuid from the old repo into the new one and rename the old repo to something like _old.  Now rename the new repo back to the original name.  If you had any hook scripts, you'll need to copy them over to the new repo as well.

This should recover your repository up until that last change was done when the computer blue screened.